# slidedown menu, synchronise sliding content jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I have built a simple slide down menu with jquery and can be found at
http://testsiteproject.bugs3.com/

My question rises when I click on the grey top button, I also want the black button to follow down with the menu instead of appearing after the div has already slided down. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<div id="topMenu">
<div id="top-top"></div>
<a href='javascript:slideMenuUp();'>
<div id="top-bottom"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

I say that it should slide down "topMenu" which includes both "top-top" and "top-bottom". But it only slides "top-top".

```
function slideMenu(){
    if ($("#topMenu").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#topMenu").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $("#topMenu").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try positioning the whole `#topMenu` div off the screen (with a negative top value), then animating on the `top` property instead of `slideDown`.

A quick mockup of what I mean:

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/vLeyF/

**JS:**

```
$("#topMenu").animate({top: 0}, "slow");
```

Then from here you can just animate back to whatever `top` property you had before etc. However, looking at Spokey's answer, you'll probably still need to do that part of it too (switch `#top-bottom` from `position:absolute` to `position:relative`).

Comment: Or you can keep the button on screen and toggle the menu. http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/vLeyF/2/

Comment: @Spokey nice idea. Looking at his current implementation, he uses 2 different tabs, but if he ever used just the one style, your fiddle would be a nice implementation!

Comment: Thanks for the answer worked great, went with your solution and abandoned "slidedown" =)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `#top-bottom` position from `absolute` to `relative`.

```
#top-bottom{
    position: relative;
    left:45%;
    height: 50px;
    width:100px;
    background:url(../images/top-up.png) no-repeat;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `.slideToggle` instead of `.slideDown`.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hMsTJ/1/

jQuery:

```
$('#topContent').hide();
// Add animation
$('#topMenu a').click(function(){
    $('#topContent').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: `slideToggle` is a good way to eliminate the odd `if` statement required to know in what direction the element should slide, however, won't he will still run into the same issue he is having with `#top-bottom`?

Comment: I changed the html/css code as well in my jsfiddle so the `#top-bottom` issue is gone. `<div id="topMenu">
    <div id="topContent">
        Put here some content
    </div>
    <a href='#'>Click me</a>
</div>`

Comment: If you position the #topmenu absolute in the bottom. It works the same as in the top. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hMsTJ/3/

Comment: I see that, nice. However, the OP currently uses 2 different tab images (a white and a black one), could this approach support that?

Comment: You can use toggleClass, see this example http://jsfiddle.net/hMsTJ/5/ This class you can define with another background image or colors.